# GCM Message received on device but not delivered to app after phone is restarted

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have added the `GCM` notification service on android which works fine but when the device gets restarted I don't see any message delivered to the app.

I checked the logs printed and it shows me a log saying:

```
"I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.package.name 0:1438085xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

and it means the message is received by the device but it is not forwarded to the app. Any suggestions?

**Here's how my implementation for onMessageReceived:**

public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

```
Logger.info(TAG, "GOT PUSH NOTIFICATION");

final Session session = Session.getInstance();
if(session == null){
    Logger.error("Not Handling Message.\nSession does not exist.");
    return;
}else{
    if(session.apiKey == null){
        Logger.error("Not Handling Message.\nUser is not Logged In.");
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * IF ACTIVITY IS IN CLOSED STATE STOP PRICE TIMER
 * */

if(session.activityInClosedState){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Logger.info("Stopping Price Timer");
            session.stopTimer();
        }
    }).start();
}

/** ALWAYS WORKS IN BACKGROUND THREAD*/
try{
    PushNotification pushNotification = new PushNotification(data);
    updateNotificationBar(pushNotification);
    session.onNewAlert();
}catch (Exception ex){
    Logger.error("Exception: "+ex);
}
```

}

Here is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.sentieo.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sentieo.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".objects.Session"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--GCM REGISTRATION STARTS -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.sentieo.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".pushnotifications.GCMListenerService$NotificationCancelledBroadCastReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        >
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".pushnotifications.RegistrationIntentService" android:enabled="true"></service>
    <service
        android:name=".pushnotifications.GCMListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".pushnotifications.InstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--GCM REGISTRATION ENDS -->
</application>
```

Comment: How are you handling the message? Have you implemented the broadcast receiver + intent service + added permissions to your app?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli: Yes. I did. And it works fine when i first install my app. Even if i kill my app and restart it , then also i receive messages. But when I restart my phone, no message received by the device is delivered to the app.

Comment: Is the broadcast registered inside the manifest? Share the piece of manifest file

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli: I have pasted manifest file as an answer. Please Check

Comment: Please add the manifest file in your question and not as an answer. And also add the code for `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: @PrerakSola: Hey I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but try adding the following lines to your `RegistrationIntentService` service: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.centio.gcm.pushnotifications.RegistrationIntentService" />
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: this doesn't help. When I looked at the logs again, I found this: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{23ab12c1 u0 com.sentieo/.pushnotifications.GCMListenerService}

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these permission in your `receiver` tag of the manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also put this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```